# How to check whether or not a matrix must have entries of opposite signs?

Tags: matlab, matrix

What I am interested in seeing is if there is an easy way to show that a large set of matrices (cannot) have columns where there is 1 positive number and 1 negative number. Therefore, I would want to take the following matrix and return false:

```
[    0, p1_2,    0, p1_4,     0,  p1_4,    0, p1_4,     0]
[ p2_1,    0,    0,    0, -p2_1, -p2_1,    0,    0, -p2_1]
[ p3_1, p3_2, p3_3,    0,     0,     0, p3_2, p3_3,  p3_3]
[    0,    0, p4_3, p4_4,  p4_4,     0, p4_4,    0,     0]
```

where all of the entries are symbolic variables restricted to the reals.
As one can see, from column 6 (6), we have p1_4 and p2_1 being the same sign. From (9) we have p2_1 and p3_3 the same sign. However from (8) we would have p1_4 and p3_3 being opposite signs and so we would want to return a fail and throw out this matrix from consideration.

Any ideas on doing? Thanks! (Btw, I am working in matlab)

Comment: Column 6 has  `-p2_1`, not `p2_1`. And how do you know `p1_4` and `p2_1` have the same sign? Are all those variables positive?

Comment: Just a side note: you probably created 16 variables named ``p1_1`` to ``p4_4``. This would be more matlab-like to store those variables in one matrix ``p`` and adress each variable by real indices: ``p(1,1)`` to ``p(4,4)``. i.e. do not hide indices in variable names, but rather really use indices as indices.

Comment: Yes, Column 6 has `-p2_1` but that means that `-p2_1` and `p1_4` have opposite signs which then implies that `p2_1` and `p1_4` have the same sign. All the variables are just symbolic variables restricted to the reals.

Answer (score 0):

*This answers the initial version of the question, which didn't mention that variables are symbolic*:

What you want can be achieved by

```
any(any(sign(A)==-1, 1) & any(sign(A)==1, 1), 2)
```

where `A` is your matrix.

*How it works*: `any(sign(A)==-1, 1)` is a row vector which contains `1` for columns that have some negative number. `any(sign(A)==1, 1)` is similar but for positive numbers. `&` checks, for each column, if both conditions are satisfied. The outermost `any` checks if that happens for *some* column.

If you have several matrices stored in a 3D array as `B(:,:,1)`, `B(:,:,2)`, ..., you can use almost the same code:

```
squeeze(any(any(sign(B)==-1, 1) & any(sign(B)==1, 1), 2))
```

This will give you a vector of length `size(B,3)`, where each entry contains the result for one of the matrices.

Comment: In this case, we have symbolic variables and so there is no explicit/implicit restriction of any of the variables being > or < 0. This method would work with numerical values, but not symbolic variables.

Comment: You should have said _from the beginning_ that they are symbolic variables!!

Comment: My apologies for that.